# How to convert the date selected using sql query in dd/mm/yy without the Z and the T in react.js?

Tags: mysql

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM `appointment` WHERE doctor_id = 1 AND appointment_date <= DATE_ADD(`appointment_date`, INTERVAL 7 DAY)"
```

This is the SQL query that I am using in the backend. I want to retrieve the date without the Z and the T.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can handle  iso-8601 timestamp

you can use `DATE_FORMAT` to get your wanted result (see example).

More Formatting possibilities see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

another possibility is `STR_TO_DATE` see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

> ```
> select date_format("2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z","%d/%I/%Y")
> ```
>
> ```
> | date_format("2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z","%d/%I/%Y") |
> | :------------------------------------------------- |
> | 12/08/2011                                         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ed15bc17471f40714973473d3c839ea)*